# Distance between two n-dimensional points (NASM)

Tags: c, floating-point, assembly, coordinate-system

I just finished writing a function that computes the distance between two n-dimensional points.

The original one was written in C and it's basically a translation of this formula:

\$\text{dist}(x,y)=\sqrt{\sum_{i^1}^d{(x_i-y_i)^2}}\$

Here's the C code for completeness sake:

```
void distanceC(float* source, float* destination, int dimensions, float* result){       
    // sqrt(sum((source-destination)^2, dimensions)))
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < dimensions; i++){
        *result += powf(source[i] - destination[i], 2);
    }
    *result = sqrtf(*result);
}
```

Finally, here's the NASM version that I wrote (I stripped some useless parts):

```
section .data           

; masks used to set exceeding items to 0 when vectors are not multiple of 4

align 16
mask1:  dd      0xffffffff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
align 16
mask2:  dd      0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0x00, 0x00
align 16
mask3:  dd      0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0x00

section .text   

Source      equ     8
Destination equ     12
Dimensions  equ     16
Result      equ     20

        ; ------------------------------------------------------------
        ; Distance between two points in n-dimensional space
        ; ------------------------------------------------------------
distance:       
        ; ------------------------------------------------------------
        ; Entering the function
        ; ------------------------------------------------------------
        push    ebp             
        mov     ebp, esp        
        sub     esp, 4          
        push    ebx             
        push    esi
        push    edi     

        ; ------------------------------------------------------------
        ; Reading parameters from stack
        ; ------------------------------------------------------------
        mov     esi, [ebp+Source]   
        mov     edi, [ebp+Destination]
        mov     ecx, [ebp+Dimensions]
        mov     eax, [ebp+Result]   

        ; let's compute how many iterations do I need by doind Dimensions/4
        ; the result will tell how many packed iterations are needed, while the remainder will tell
        ; if I need we have exceeding items that require a final masked operation
        push    eax                     
        mov     edx, 0                  
        mov     eax, ecx                
        mov     ebx, 4                  
        div     ebx                     
        mov     ecx, eax                ; ecx becomes the counter for the packed iterations
        pop     eax                     

        ; now ecx contains the packed counter while edx contains the number of the exceeding items
        ; xmm0 = result
        ; xmm1 = source's components
        ; xmm2 = destination's components
        ; ebx  = both vector's offset
        mov     ebx, 0      
        xorps   xmm0, xmm0              ; setting xmm0 to 0 (may not be needed)

        ; we may have a situation in which vector's size is less than 4, and this means
        ; that we don't have any packed iteration to do but we'll jump to the final
        ; masked execution
        cmp     ecx, 0
        je      .dU1                    

.loopP: movaps  xmm1, [esi+ebx*4]       ; let's get Source's next 4 items
        movaps  xmm2, [edi+ebx*4]       ; and Destination's next 4 ones
        subps   xmm1, xmm2              ; (Source-Destination)
        mulps   xmm1, xmm1              ; (Source-Destination)^2
        dec     ecx                     ; let's decrease ecx since we just did one iteration
        haddps  xmm1, xmm1
        haddps  xmm1, xmm1              ; let's sum the partial results that we have in xmm1
        addps   xmm0, xmm1              ; let's add the new computed results to the total
        jz      .loopC                  ; if ecx is 0 we're done with the packed iterations
        add     ebx, 1                  ; let's move the offset to next elements
        jmp     .loopP                  ; next iteration

        ; the packed loop is done, let's see if we have some exceeding items that are needing the masked iteration
        ; if not we jump to the square root
.loopC  cmp     edx, 0
        je      .endD                   ; edx = 0 means no masked iterations,

        ; if we didn't jump than we have to deal with the masked iteration
        ; we need to decide which mask to apply and we decide it based on edx's value   

.dU1:   cmp     edx, 1          
        jne     .dU2                    ; if edx is not 1 than it may be 2
        ; if edx is 1 then we use mask1
        movaps  xmm7, [mask1]           
        jmp     .dU                     ; now that I have the correct mask I can jump to the actual execution

.dU2:   cmp     edx, 2
        jne     .dU3
        movaps  xmm7, [mask2]
        jmp     .dU

.dU3:   movaps  xmm7, [mask3]           ; if I'm here than I can only use the third mask since the previous checks failed

        ; let's apply the mask and complete the computation     
.dU:    movaps  xmm1, [esi+ebx*4]       ; let's get Source's next 4 items
        movaps  xmm2, [edi+ebx*4]       ; and Destination's next 4 ones 
        andps   xmm1, xmm7              ; masking
        andps   xmm2, xmm7              ; masking

        ; now I can use the same instructions of the packed loop but just once
        subps   xmm1, xmm2              ; (Source-Destination)          
        mulps   xmm1, xmm1              ; (Source-Destination)^2
        haddps  xmm1, xmm1      
        haddps  xmm1, xmm1              ; let's sum the partial results that we have in xmm1
        addps   xmm0, xmm1              ; let's add the new computed results to the total

        ; finally we need to apply the square root and copy the result where eax is pointing
.endD:  sqrtps  xmm0, xmm0              
        movss   [eax], xmm0             

        ; ------------------------------------------------------------
        ; Exiting the function
        ; ------------------------------------------------------------

        pop edi             
        pop esi
        pop ebx
        mov esp, ebp        
        pop ebp             
        ret
```

(You can test it by calling it from a C program, just add `global distance`)

The question is: is there any way to make it faster or just write it better?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Wrong increment

First, there is a bug in your main loop.  This line:

```
    add     ebx, 1
```

should be:

```
    add     ebx, 4
```

because you are operating on 4 floats at a time.  Right now, you are doing array elements [0..3] following by [1..4].  On my computer the program crashed because it had a problem doing an unaligned load.

### Simplify divide by 4

This part where you divide ecx by 4:

```
    push    eax                     
    mov     edx, 0                  
    mov     eax, ecx                
    mov     ebx, 4                  
    div     ebx                     
    mov     ecx, eax                ; ecx becomes the counter for the packed iterations
    pop     eax
```

can be simplified to this:

```
    mov     edx, ecx
    and     edx, 3
    shr     ecx, 2
```

Explanation: `shr` is the shift right instruction.  When you shift right by 2 it is the same thing as dividing by 4.  To get the remainder of something divided by 4, you just need to `and` that number with 3.  C equivalent code:

```
    remainder = length & 3;
    length >>= 2;
```

### Remove one jump from main loop

Your main loop:

```
.loopP: movaps  xmm1, [esi+ebx*4]
        movaps  xmm2, [edi+ebx*4]
        subps   xmm1, xmm2
        mulps   xmm1, xmm1
        dec     ecx
        haddps  xmm1, xmm1
        haddps  xmm1, xmm1
        addps   xmm0, xmm1
        jz      .loopC
        add     ebx, 4
        jmp     .loopP

.loopC  cmp     edx, 0
        je      .endD
```

Can be rewritten to remove one of the jumps at the end:

```
.loopP: movaps  xmm1, [esi+ebx*4]
        movaps  xmm2, [edi+ebx*4]
        subps   xmm1, xmm2
        add     ebx, 4
        mulps   xmm1, xmm1
        dec     ecx
        haddps  xmm1, xmm1
        haddps  xmm1, xmm1
        addps   xmm0, xmm1
        jnz      .loopP

        cmp     edx, 0
        je      .endD
```

By the way, I also noticed another bug here.  When you exit the loop you currently are skipping the `add ebx, 4` line.  But you need to advance `ebx` or else the remainder part below won't have the right value for `ebx`.  This works correctly in my modified version because I always add to `ebx` inside the loop.

### Loading the mask

The part where you do a chain of compares to load one of three masks:

```
.dU1:   cmp     edx, 1          
        jne     .dU2
        movaps  xmm7, [mask1]           
        jmp     .dU

.dU2:   cmp     edx, 2
        jne     .dU3
        movaps  xmm7, [mask2]
        jmp     .dU

.dU3:   movaps  xmm7, [mask3]
```

can be simplified to this:

```
.dU1:   shl     edx, 4
        movaps  xmm7, [mask1 + edx - 16]
```

Explanation: Your masks are located in memory in consecutive order like an array of 128 bit values.  So you can load them by index.  Note  that `edx` is 1..3 here.  The `shl` instruction is shift left, and shifting left by 4 multiplies `edx` by 16.  Then we load from mask1 + edx - 16.  The minus 16 is because `edx` started at one instead of zero.  Equivalent C code is something like this:

```
        uint8_t mask1[48] = { /* values */ };
        mask128 = *(__m128 *) &mask1[(remainder<<4)-16];
```

### Stack push/pop

I'm not sure if this is part of your calling convention, but your prologue and epilogue have extraneous instructions:

```
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi

    pop     edi 
    pop     esi
    pop     ebx
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

Could be changed to:

```
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi

    pop     edi
    pop     esi
    pop     ebx
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

Furthermore, you are not utilizing `eax`.  If you used `eax` instead of `ebx` everywhere in your function, you wouldn't have to save `ebx` because you wouldn't ever use it.  You can load the result pointer into `eax` at the very end instead of at the beginning.

### Comments

In general I liked all your comments.  The one thing I thought you could add a comment for was that this double instruction:

```
        haddps  xmm1, xmm1
        haddps  xmm1, xmm1
```

adds all 4 floats in `xmm1` into the first float in `xmm1`.  I wasn't familiar with the `haddps` instruction and I initially thought you made a typo (I thought a single `haddps` would do the whole job).

### Alignment required

I was able to use the function successfully, but when I modified my `main()`, the program crashed.  The difference was that my modification caused the arrays I passed to `distance()` to be not aligned to 16 bytes.  Since the `movaps` instruction expects 128 bit alignment, the arrays passed in need to have 128 bit alignment.  I think you should switch to the `movups` instruction which handles unaligned floats.

Comment: Thanks for your great feedback. I'm using `add     ebx, 1` because I've got `movaps  xmm1, [esi+ebx*4]` so it's still moving each 4 items. I don't know which one is faster but I think that the code is correct. Removing the jump is a great idea, but can you please add some explanation to the division and the masking parts? I'd like to understand what I write. Finally, I'm using `movaps` because I'm aligning my data in the caller, so I'm sure that it won't lead to a segfault.

Comment: @StepTNT A float is 4 bytes so `ebx*4` will advance one float per one `ebx`.  You need to advance 16 bytes per iteration, so add 4 to `ebx`.  I'll try to add more explanation to the other parts.

Comment: I know that a float is 4 bytes, but I'm actually advancing on pointers, that's why `ebx*4` moves to the next 4 items. If not, I couldn't explain why it does work :)

Comment: @StepTNT Does it really work though?  It didn't for me.  Did you test it with test values against a working C version?

Comment: I'm testing it by checking which points are taken at each iteration, and they seem the correct ones. BTW I just discovered that it still works even if I remove completely the `add`, which is a bit odd. If you need it I can post a little snippet of my dataset with the result of the execution because I may be overlooking something.

Comment: @StepTNT Test with these values: `0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0` vs `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0` and pass in a length of 8.  I got with +4: 10 and with +1: 14.14.  Also I made an edit to my modified code, I removed an extraneous sub ebx after the end of the loop.

Comment: Oh dear, forgive me but I was working with the wrong dataset. Actually `add ebx, 1` leads to segfault because I'm using `movaps` instead of `movups` while `add ebx, 4` is 100% fine. Thank you for your reply and sorry for wasting your time like this!

Comment: Just a quick note: why did you change `shl     edx, 2` to `shl     edx, 4` ? It worked fine with 2, using 4 leads to wrong masks.

Comment: @StepTNT It made the explanation easier.  I also changed the next line, which used to read `movaps  xmm7, [mask1 + edx*4 - 16]` to `movaps  xmm7, [mask1 + edx - 16]` (notice I don't multiply edx by 4 because I shifted it by two extra already).  Both ways should be equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

This comment:

```
; ------------------------------------------------------------
; Entering the function
; ------------------------------------------------------------
```

is a little useless; it's it quite obvious that the start of the function/subroutine is right there.

However, the rest of your comments are very detailed and very well placed.

---

Don't use `dec`; using `sub REG, 1` is faster.

`dec` runs in 1 CPU cycle. `sub REG, 1` runs in half a CPU cycle.

Source: [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75361/countdown-program-in-x86-nasm#comment137057_75371)

---

Other than that, I'm not too familiar with `xmm` registers and the instructions that go with them.

However, as I look into them, if any improvements pop into my head, I'll update my post.

Comment: I have that first comment because this one's part of a bigger file with multiple functions so I use them as separators between functions. Thanks for the link, I'll change all the `inc`/`dec` with `add`/`sub`.

Answer (score 3):

**Defining the masks.**

If you are willing to address the masks through the `movups` instruction then a 50% gain in storage for these masks can be achieved. The reduced alignment condition will further add to this gain.

```
align 4
masks:  dd      0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
```

Now *mask1* can be found at address [masks+8 **-0**]
Now *mask2* can be found at address [masks+8 **-4**]
Now *mask3* can be found at address [masks+8 **-8**].

**Using the masks.**

Comparing EDX to 0 can also be done through decrementing EDX and watching for the sign flag. A simple negation of EDX gives the negative offset needed to fetch the correct mask.

```
.loopC:  dec    edx                     ;{0,1,2,3} -> {-1,0,1,2}
         js     .endD                   ;No masked iterations
         neg    edx                     ;{0,1,2} -> {0,-1,-2}
         movups xmm7, [masks+8 + edx*4]
```

**Size optimizations.**

To clear the EBX register use `xor ebx,ebx`. It is shorter than `mov ebx,0`.

To jump if the ECX register is clear use `jecxz .loopC`. It is shorter than the combo `cmp ecx,0` `je .dU1`. Please note that I changed the destination to cope with the possibility of the argument *Dimensions* being zero! Your code would erroneously have used *mask3* in this case.

Comment: Thak you for your comment, I like your idea on how to use masks! BTW there's no further check on input's size because it's guaranteed that there's at least one element, so `Dimensions` can't be 0 (I check for it in the caller function)